# Trying to get the distance with C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, geolocation, distance

I need to discover which is the closer item in main list which its items have latitude and longitude. I came across this script, and I am using to return the distance in kilometers...but the item returned isn't is the closer item...does someone know why it didn't work? thank u very much!
I am using xamarin forms c#
my English is not that good, sorry.

```
public static Loja EncontraLojaPerto(List<Loja> lojaList, double lat1, 
double lon1, char unit)
    {
        Loja lojaProxima = new Loja();
        double distAuxiliar = -1;

        foreach (var item in lojaList)
        {
            double lat2 = Convert.ToDouble(item.latitude.Replace('.',','));
            double lon2 = Convert.ToDouble(item.longitude.Replace('.',','));

            Func<double, double> deg2Rad = (x) => (x * (Math.PI / 180));
            Func<double, double> rad2Deg = (x) => (x / Math.PI * 180.0);

            var theta = lon1 - lon2;
            var dist = Math.Sin(deg2Rad(lat1)) * Math.Sin(deg2Rad(lat2)) + Math.Cos(deg2Rad(lat1)) * Math.Cos(deg2Rad(lat2)) * Math.Cos(deg2Rad(theta));

            dist = Math.Acos(dist);
            dist = rad2Deg(dist);
            dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

            switch (unit)
            {
                case 'K':
                    dist = dist * 1.609344;
                    break;
                case 'N':
                    dist = dist * 0.8684;
                    break;
            }

            //verificando se essa pode ser a distância menor
            int retval = distAuxiliar.CompareTo(dist);

            if (retval > 0 || distAuxiliar.Equals(-1))
            {
                distAuxiliar = dist;
                lojaProxima = item;
            }
        }

        return lojaProxima;
    }
```

I was searching for a answer and I found it: here, in Brazil we use ',' instead '.' and '.' instead ','...then, My webservice give me a numver with '.' when I need a ',', then I used .Replace to replace the '.', but, when I use it, the number change its quantity of character (if it was 123.4300 now it is 123,43)...when I used the Replace, the numbers worked but the foreach never finish and I never arrive in the 'return' line...

Comment: have you attempted to debug this at all?  For each item in the list, verify that the distance calc is returning the right value.  Then once you've verified that, figure out why the distance comparison is returning the wrong item.

Comment: I am doing it now..

Comment: I used other iternet codes about it and the result is always the same wrong item...I think there is something about this method that I don't know

Comment: or my implementation (the if ) is wrong]

Comment: I discovered that when I convert string to double ... the ", " of the double dissapears...

Comment: try using Double.Parse instead - it gives you more control over formatting and locale

Comment: @Jason it worked for me
thank u very much

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of the *haversine* formula seems to be wrong. It should be:

```
a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin²(Δλ/2)
c = 2 ⋅ atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
d = R ⋅ c
```

where `φ` is latitude, `λ` is longitude and `R` is earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km);

[Source](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: @JoycedeLanna Nothing special, you can do everything with the functions defined in `System.Math`. `Δφ` and `Δλ` are simply the increments of latitude and longitude between both points.

Comment: there are numerous C# implementations of this function on SO and elsewhere on the web

Comment: The problem is that my webservice give me a number with a dot instead comma...but when I use .Replace it work a little then stop